# Question about Regex to edit claim and remove part of email / username

Tags: regex, adfs, claims-based-identity

Completely new to regex only read a few guides my problem is as follows. A 3rd party solution is being connected to our Adfs 2016 enviroment. We have run into a problem as the solution cannot handle long usernames and the Upn and email of our users are in the format of users initials 3 or 4 letters.department@ourcompany.com, so Dave Dibley Jr would be ddj.department@ourcompany.com

what i would like to do is use Regex to Cut everything after the initals from the claim any suggestions how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx for string manipulation in the Claims Rules Language. Fx:

c:[type == “http://contoso.com/role”]
 => issue (Type = “http://contoso.com/role”, Value = RegExReplace(c.Value, “(?i)director”, “Manager“);

Pass through any role claims.  If any of the claims contain the word “Director”, RegExReplace() will change it to “Manager”.  For example, “Director of Finance” would pass through as “Manager of Finance”.

See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16161.ad-fs-2-0-using-regex-in-the-claims-rule-language.aspx for more information.